# How can I make a bold horizontal rule under list of symbols (nomenclature) title?

Tags: nomenclature

I want to place lines under the list of symbols(nomenclature) to make it more distinctive. How can I do that? I want to achieve something like this[image]

Comment: Please add a [**minimal** but **working** example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and solve your issue if we see **compilable** code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In case that the document class matter to show properly the issue in the MWE, supply also a URL to download the class (unless it is one provided usually by TeX distributions). Otherwise make the MWE with a standard class like `book`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

\centering\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols

\hfill
\hline
\smallskip
\hline
\hfill
}

\nomenclature{A(T_{n})}{Alternate triangular snake}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image]